# What's »Aldää« in »Ey jo, was geht, Aldää?«

Tags: meaning, word-usage, colloquial

As I was looking up the word *ey* in dict.cc, I noticed a rather interesting colloquial expression:

> [Ey jo, was geht, Aldää? [ugs.] = Whazzup? [coll.]](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Ey%20jo%2C%20was%20geht%2C%20Ald%C3%A4%C3%A4%3F)

What does *Aldää* mean above? I could not find the word in *the Duden* or any of the four other online dictionaries I use.

Comment: It is used in the sense of 'my old buddy'

Comment: The Austrian (specially Viennese) equivalent is: »Oida« https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuXR53ex4iI sometimes also written as »Olta«: https://images.kurier.at/46-60636254.jpg/55.690.541

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I would not say it's especially Viennese. It's also used very commonly in Upper Austria.

Comment: It is simply a dialect version of "Alter"

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Tofros answer is not wrong, but imho there is a different angle to it.

First of all "Aldää" is phonetic spelling for "Alter". This is German slang. It used to be teenage slang but by now it's pretty much general slang since the teenagers from back then are now 30+ and still use it.

In your example it is used as a form of adress. The translation to "Whazzup?" is kind of incomplete. I would say it's something like "Whazzup dude?". So "Alter" would translate to "dude", "man", "bro" or the like.

"Alter" can also be used as an exclamation. E.g. "Boah Alter!" would be something like "Awwww maaan!".

Literally it also translates to "age" and "old man" but in this context it means something completely different. Most people will not think of the original meaning when they hear it.

In northern Germany there is a similar slang. Often "Digger" is used instead of "Alter". Again "Digger" is phonetic spelling for "Dicker" literally meaning "overweight person" and again this original literal meaning is widely ignored in that context.

The English analogy would be "bro". If I call someone my bro, no one would assume that he is my blood relative.

Comment: *Aldä* is not *the* phonetic spelling of *Alter* but one of many. Depending on where you are from, *Alter* may sound more like *Alda, Aldor, Aldeä* or *Alda* or even *Alta*

Comment: or *ahle* ... which I was told was part of colloquial greetings ("Hej, ahle, wej?") already when my grandfather was young about 100 years ago. You may also want to take into account that an alter Freund is not necessarily an aged person - the "age" refers to the friendship, so also two teens can be alte Freunde.

Comment: The "traditional" *Alter* I was using when I was a teen is IMHO a bit different from what kids use today - We were using it to address each other like you say - "buddy" or even "bro". *Aldä*, as my kids use it today, is just a "cool" filler and doesn't mean anything beyond "Hey" or "Gosh" or "listen to me".

Comment: I've heard some people who use those word a lot claim that when referring to someone "Alter" and "Digger" originally were simply short for something like "alter Freund" or "dicker Kumpel" (_dick_ meaning close in this context). To them it never had anything to do with age or weight (and therefore it is not used ironically as claimed in the other answer by tofro).

Comment: @Kapep as tofro mentioned in a now deleted comment, he did not say that it is used ironically. He said that the fact that it is used by young people IS ironic. I misread that too :-)

Comment: @AndréStannek Oh you're right, I misread that. In that case I agree, it is ironic

Comment: I get a Werner vibe from this.

Comment: Yet another angle: Where I come from certain people use "Alter" (or Alder)  to refer to other male friends and "Alte" (or Alde) to refer to female friends.

Comment: And don't forget *Oida*, the Viennese pronunciation.

Comment: @MrPaulch Correct; but "meine/Deine/seine Alte" is the female partner, with a slightly derogatory undercurrent.

Comment: FWIW: "Alter" as well as "Dicker" are used in the song [*Türlich, türlich (sicher Dicker)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LHe9m9VtXI) (by "Das Bo", from 2000): [*Was geht'n Alder?* \[…\] *Sicher Dicker* \[…\] *Mann, Alder*](https://genius.com/Das-bo-turlich-turlich-sicher-dicker-lyrics).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider true. But I heard the terms in both connotations. "Hey Alde, was geht" referring to a female friend. And also "Meine Alte geht heute aus" referring to ones partner.

Answer (score 13):

That is colloquial teen speak and simply means

> Alter!

(old man!)

And is ironically normally used between teens of ages around 11-16 to refer to each other (it is even used by and used to address girls). Later on, some of them eventually learn how to properly speak German :)

Comment: Except in that case it doesn't mean "old man".

Comment: @Em1 Well, it still *means* "old man" - It's, however, not *meant to mean* it ;)

Comment: @tofro At least in my teen-ingroup "Alter" was short for "Alter Schwede" not "Alter Mann", so maybe better use "old one" as translation then "old man"? - other then that good answer.

Comment: Alter comes from the Roman greeting "Altera Pars", which means "The other part of me", which was a way of expressing a brotherly connection. This was then picked up by the slaves, which had no clue what it meant, and spread through germania

Comment: @Dynamitos sicher nicht.

Comment: @tofro It was taught like this from my german teacher and i trusted she was telling the truth, not a german professor myself

Comment: @AngeloFuchs where exactly do you see the fundamental difference between "old one" and "old man"?

Comment: http://www.witzcharts.de/witze/fritzchen-witze/alter-fritzchen-fahrt-freihandig-fahrrad-als.html

Comment: @tofro "one" is far broader then "man". e.G. a woman can be "one" but not "man". As with the example of "Alter Schwede", "old man" would be incorrect, "old one" just incomplete.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs And how exactly would "Alte**r**" fit a woman - that's clearly male? And why would you want to imply a male swede wouldn't be a man? Sorry, don't get it. Also don't get how Swedes relate to "Aldaa" at all.

Comment: The term "Alter" to address one another has transcended its original meaning of "old man", it has become a new term, more or less. My guess is that girls picked it up simply because all their male friends were using it and "Alte" has a slightly different, usually derogatory meaning. But it really is used by girls to address each other, but only ones that would like being associated with being "ghetto" and "gangster", AFAIK

Comment: @tofro It refers to swedes as I pointed out in my first comment in the way that in my teen-ingroup "Alter" never refereed "Alter Mann" but only "Alter Schwede".

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I guess that is an assumption: "Aldää" could derive from "alter [Schwerenöter|Geizkragen|Schlingel|Verwalter|...]" or it could simply stand alone like in "Mein Alter ist gestern wieder besoffen heimgekommen". As the term seems to be mainly used by teens of Turkish origin according to my kids, I doubt a bit it really is in any way related to "alter Schwede". Or would you happen to have any proof for this claim?

Comment: Can we get back on topic and just say again, that "Alter" almost never refers to the actual age of the person, ironically or not.

Comment: More rant than an answer. Even if, it's quite wrong.

Comment: @OddDev More a rant over an answer than a comment. Even if it's quite wrong. You could elaborate a bit on *what you think is * "quite wrong".

Comment: @tofro It's simply the fact, that "Alter" does not translate into "old man" in this context. Also I strongly disagree with the assumption that this is teenager language. Even my boss's boss occasionally uses "Alter" to express astonishment. (In such a context it would for example translate in something like "what the heck".) And he's about 40 years old and a highly educated manager responsible for about 100 employees.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed *Alter* is used in colloquial (once teenage) slang to express astonishment, or to address friends. Both of these usages are not too recent really, as similarly used proverbs did long exist:

> [Alter Schwede!](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alter_Schwede_(Redewendung))  (known from 17. Century)
>   Na, mein [alter Knabe](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=Adelung&lemid=DK01478)! (age of origin unclear, possibly related to *Knappe*)

Today both proverbs are elliptically shortened.

Comment: I've also heard "alter Verwalter" and found variants of it on the internet.

On [this website](http://gesichtspunkte.de/?p=14117) someone reports the following:

„Alter Verwalter“, sagt eine Wienerin, sei so ungefähr dasselbe wie „Du bist aber gscheit“.

Does anybody know whether this Viennese woman is right?

Comment: @AshwinSchumann I'm a native german speaker and I never heard of using it in that way. "Alter Verwalter" is more used to express astonishment and I'd claim that it has neither positive nor negative connotation. For example if you buy lettuce dressing that needs to be stored in the refrigerator, but your wife puts it always next to the oil in a closet. If you are about to dump a full bottle for the fifth time this week, you can say "Alter Verwalter, das glaub ich nicht." as "Jeez, I can't believe it". But you could use it aswell to express gratitude, like if you find it once in the fridge ;)

Comment: @Felix.C Right, my experience as well - Both *Aldä* and *Alter Verwalter* are more an expression along the lines of "gosh" or "jeez" than really addressing anyone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also a native Speaker and would like to shed some light on the usage of all these terms:

- "Alter" (or any of its wrong spellings Alda, Alder etc.) is a very
  colloquial way to address a male person, usually a friend, but like
  in English you can also use it on strangers. It used to refer to an 'old' friendship. You can compare it to "old chap" in English.
- "Dicker" (or its other wrong spellings Digger, Digga etc.) is used only among friends, unless you want to insult someone, since it literally means 'fat'. Colloquially it is an abbreviation for "dicker Freund" meaning 'chummer' or 'close friend' in English. 'dick' (translates to 'thick', since both are germanic words) refers to the strength of the bond, not to the size of the Person.
- @AshwinSchumann "Alter Verwalter" is just used for the Rhyme. It is an Exclamation of Astonishment similar to "holy moly" in English.

Answer (score 2):

As someone from Franconia, I’d also like to add what all other answers have glanced over: *Aldää!* doesn’t sound like the canonical *Alter!* to me. It much more closely resembles the colloquial expression for *Alte*, which I would probably render as *Alde* or, especially if the end of it is stressed and dragged out, as *Aldä(ä)* (a match in writing).*

*Alde* is a bit different in usage.
Some male friends may refer to their girlfriends with this expression when those aren’t present (*Mei Alde is‘ im Playboy drin!* and *Ka Alde, ka G’schrei* are samples taken from lyrics by the band J.B.O. (might be considered NSFW))
It’s also used by some – I’d say primarily and by cliché older or even elderly – husbands to refer to their wives and likewise to call and address them, especially in folk comedy shows. (I would expect it to be said like *Alde, was gibts’n heud zu Middach?* (*Ehefrau, was gibt es denn heute zum Mittagessen?*).) (I still vaguely remember such a show from when I was a child but I can’t recall its name. Trying to rediscover it (without luck), I at least [found some other written samples.](https://www.google.de/search?q="mei+alde"+wirtschaft))

*: 
I would describe the sound as something inbetween the two (It doesn’t feel to me like any of the two really covers it, maybe just like the ending *-er* doesn’t exactly sound like *E* and *R* pronounced one after the other.)

Comment: Hey Keno, welcome to the German language StackExchange, and thank you for your contribution. You may want to take a look at the [tour], if you like, or visit [help] for more information about the features of this site.

Answer (score 1):

Aldää comes from "Alter" (old person, friend), but it does not mean in any sense that the person is old. It is more used between young under-educated men/boys. There is something similar, "mein Alter", "meine Alte", which means "my boy-friend", "my girl-friend" or also husband/wife. This is also used by older under-educated people, and it is not so modern. 
In former times "mein Alter" meant also "my father", "meine Alten" meant also "my parents".
"Wohnst Du noch bei Deinen Alten?" = "Do you live still at your parents?". But I think it is mostly not more used in that sense now.